# Warum schreibt man „nämlich“ nicht mit stummem „h“?

Tags: spelling

Das Wort *nämlich* wird doch mit einem langen *ä* gesprochen. Gibt es einen guten Grund, warum man *nämlich* schreibt und nicht *nähmlich*, oder ist das einfach historisch bedingt?

Es gibt sogar ein recht bekanntes Sprichwort:

> Wer *nämlich* mit *h* schreibt, ist dämlich.

Was mich vermuten lässt, dass es nicht nur für mich seltsam ist, es ohne *h* zu schreiben.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Eines der wichtigsten Prinzipien der deutschen Orthographie ist es, die einander entsprechenden Teile von verwandten Wörtern möglichst gleich zu schreiben (*Stammprinzip*). *Nämlich* wird also so geschrieben, weil schon *Name* kein *h* enthält.

Ein langer Stammvokal in offener Silbe ist eigentlich der Normalfall und braucht nicht besonders markiert zu werden (*lesen*, *Klage*, *Vogel*); vielmehr wird es umgekehrt markiert, wenn der Vokal kurz ist (in einem hypothetischen Wort *Namme*  durch Verdopplung des folgenden Konsonanten). Vor einem *l*, *m*, *n* oder *r* kann ein langer Vokal aber zusätzlich durch ein *h* markiert werden. Dafür, wann das passiert, gibt es synchron keine Regeln; meistens richtet sich das nach sprachgeschichtlichen Gesichtspunkten.